# будет ли работать мьютекс на std::atomic_flag так как задумано?

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

Подскажите вот пример кода мьютекса идею которого я подсмотрел в одном из видео лекций МФТИ.
Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение о такой реализации и практическом использовании такого класса?

```
class my_mutex
{
public:
            my_mutex()      noexcept    =   default;
            ~my_mutex()     noexcept    { flag.clear(); }
            void lock()     noexcept    { while(flag.test_and_set()) std::this_thread::yield(); }
            bool try_lock() noexcept    { return !flag.test_and_set(); }
            void unlock()   noexcept    { flag.clear(); }

private:
    std::atomic_flag flag ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};
```

Comment: Зависит от реализации `.test_end_set()`

Comment: @avp то есть зависит от компилятора?

Comment: Если это builtin. то от компилятора, если самописный тип, то от программиста, который его писал

Comment: Это не мьютекс, это скорее спинлок. А в остальном выглядит нормально, только можно еще `std::memory_order`ы правильные расставить. А вот как выбрать между этим, мьютексом, и `.wait()` на `std::atomic` - хз.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А вы можете свой вариант кода написать как бы вы сделали? А я потом протестирую

Comment: Что вам написать, `memory_order`ы? `std::memory_order_release` в `.clear()` и `std::memory_order_acquire` в `.test_and_set()`. Вроде так.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а я подумал, другая реализация, наверно вместо `std::memory_order_acquire` тогда уже лучше `memory_order_acq_rel`

Comment: А зачем acq_rel?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вроде более жесткие правила. Никакие операции чтения или записи в памяти в текущем потоке не могут быть переупорядочены ни до загрузки, ни после сохранения. Или я не прав?

Comment: Это строже чем у стандартного мьютекса, там вроде гарантии как у acquire в lock и release в unlock.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Пусть поток `A` пытается захватить мьютекс, выполняя цикл `while` из функции `lock`, а поток `B` пытается освободить мьютекс, выполняя функцию `unlock`. Чисто формально по стандарту есть ли гарантия, что поток `A` _не_ сможет в течение сколь угодно долгого времени монополизировать доступ к атомарной переменной `flag`, не давая потоку `B` возможности изменить её состояние?

Comment: @wololo В стандарте довольно туманно написано: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress Я думаю что должно на практике работать, но на уровне железа подробностей не знаю...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Насколько я на данный момент понимаю стандарт, описанная ситуация возможна. Да, есть ощущение, что на практике будет работать. Особенное, если выполнение `std::this_thread::yield()` занимает длительный промежуток времени. Но с другой стороны, если у нас 128-ядерный процессор и на один освобождающий поток приходится 127 потоков, пытающихся захватить мьютекс, то такой расклад уже выглядит как-то угрожающе. Даже если сто потоков выполняют `yield`, ещё десятки могут в этот момент конкурировать за атомарную переменную. Да, хотелось бы больше подробностей на уровне железа.

Comment: @wololo попробуйте делать `std::this_thread::yield()`, например раз в 100 заходов что-то типа `if((cnt++ %100)==0){ std::this_thread::yield()}`

Comment: @wololo А вообще плохо когда 128 потоков хотят один ресурс это всегда узкое место.